# Passing values from ViewModel to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am making an MVC 5 web application and I am looking to pass a value from my ViewModel to a function in my JavaScript

The aim is hide a Label/Div when the user selects the option "No" and make it reappear when the user changes the option back to "Yes"

Here is what I have so far:

ViewModel:

```
public enum BasicAnswer
        {
            [Display(Name= "Yes")]
            Yes,
            [Display(Name= "No")]
            No
        }
 public BasicAnswer userDiscomfortResponse { get; set; }
```

View:

```
   <div id="UserDiscomfortAnswerLabel">
            <label id="somelabel">Did you have any discomfort with an exercise?</label>
            <div class="Answer1" onclick=feedback data-id='@Model.userDiscomfortResponse'>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.userDiscomfortResponse, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Question2">
        <label id="UserDiscomfortExerciseLabel">What exercise was the issue?</label> 
        <div class="Answer2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.discomfortExercise, Model.UsersSelectedExcerises, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function feedback() {
    var feedback = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
    if (feedback == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("UserDiscomfortExerciseLabel").style.display = "block"
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("UserDiscomfortExerciseLabel").style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is var feedback = $(this).attr('data-id') results as undefined and so the label hides on click but never shows again.

Is there something I've missed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it loading the page with an empty data-id?  Seems to me you should move the onchange onto the dropdownlist and call feedback onload also (change this in event handler to "#userDiscomfortResponse")

Comment: No, data-id='@Model.userDiscomfortResponse' has a value of "Yes" as soon as the page loads

Comment: In the Javascript is $(this) evaluating to the DIV? or is 'this' something else.  Also, try $(this).data("id") instead of attr("id")

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample code regarding your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try removing the onclick on the div and add:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function feedback() {
        var feedback = $('#userDiscomfortResponse').val()
        if (feedback == "Yes") {
            document.getElementById("UserDiscomfortExerciseLabel").style.display = "block"
        }
       else {
           document.getElementById("UserDiscomfortExerciseLabel").style.display = "none"
       }
    }

    $("#userDiscomfortResponse").change(feedback);
    feedback();
}
```

Comment: Copy and Pasted your sample got:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

On line 1

Comment: Your using JQuery right - so have you not create the javascript after your having included the jquery.js?

Comment: I dont know anymore haha xD apologies, I'm new to all this, am I missing a component?

Comment: The HTML page that contained the javascript before needs to contain the javascript in the answer.

Comment: I've replaced my original JavaScript code with the one in the answer, both pieces of code were stored in a single .JS file In my HTML I have the following: <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ReviewContentControl.js"> </script> Have I missed something?

Comment: Sounds like you have included the ReviewContentControl.js before jquery.js.  jquery.js might be included in a master page / layout page somewhere and the order is incorrect.  You can check the source in the browser and see what order they come in and then fix in the code.  You were using JQuery previously however it was probably executing later due to the onclick event which meant it was then defined

Comment: Yeah, you're right I was missing <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script> before ReviewContentControl.js So now it works, However... var feedback = $('#userDiscomfortResponse').val() The value is 0 instead of "Yes" any ideas?

Comment: The htmlHelper EnumDropDownListFor is rendering this out with integer values, so its probably 0 = Yes, 1 = No.  I would just change the If statement in the javascript, e.g .val() == 0

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes I did get it working however var feedback = $('#userDiscomfortResponse').val() returned value 0 (for Yes) 1 for (no) simply changing the if statement to reflect this made the above solution to work brilliantly, thank you